# How to handle an empty result set in tempojs?

Tags: javascript, jquery, render, tempo

The documentation is not quite clear on this, or I may not be understanding how to implement this in the HTML, but how do you handle a template in tempojs that has an empty list/array of items coming from JSON output? Is there a template directive that can be used to display something when the data list is empty (i.e. like the `else empty` in normal conditional code)?

Here's an example:

Javascript:

```
$(function() {
    /*var data = [
        {id:'1',name:'Test One',coordinates:'12.0012,-122.92'}
    ];*/
    var data = [];
    Tempo.prepare('userLocs').render(data);
});
```

HTML:

```
...
<tbody id="userLocs">
    <tr data-template>
        <td>{{name}}</td>
        <td>{{coordinates}}</td>
        <td><a href="#" data-id="{{id}}" class="delLocation">Delete</a></td>
    </tr>
    <tr data-template-fallback>
        <td colspan="3">Javascript is not available.</td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
...
```